# Most efficient for multiple distros on one machine

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

My laptop – which is my main everyday computer – is currently dual-booting Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04 (though I almost never use Windows). I recently tried out a USB boot stick of the live Debian 8.0.2 image, with the Cinnamon desktop GUI. I was very impressed, and am interested in using it. I don't want to get rid of Ubuntu, and unfortunately can't get rid of Windows (occasionally I still *have* to be able to read/write 100% docx and xlsx compatible files).

So would it be more efficient (in terms of RAM and CPU workload) to bootstrap a Debian image within Ubuntu, or actually triple-boot? I have room on the HDD for another partition, but would I need multiple partitions for grub, etc like when I initially set up the Ubuntu dual-boot? I'm well experienced with double-booting machines, but have never tried a triple.

Comment: not really. best is to uninstall `grub` - which is an anachronism on modern computers anyway. make a new folder for each installation on your esp where you'll keep each distros kernel images, do fstab entry that binds that folder over /boot when you start the distro, and get pretty menus w/ an EFI menu app like rEFInd. you could keep all distros on the same / in different chroots if you liked, or a separate btrfs subvol per - w/ dedup - or, yeah, separate partitions. bootloaders only get in your way in the main - the firmware will just boot Linux *and* windows.